# Stack around the variable 'keypoints' was corrupted

Tags: stack, detection, surf

I am using the following part code to get surf features plotted:

```
I am using the following part code to get surf features plotted:
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<vector>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
using namespace cv;


int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture vid(0);
    if (!vid.isOpened())
    {
    cout<<"Camera not present..Halting the system";
    return -1;
}
namedWindow("Camera_Inp",1);
namedWindow("Surfout",1);
Mat camcap,surfimg;
Mat grayimg;
SurfFeatureDetector featureimg(1000);

vector<KeyPoint>keypoints;
while(vid.isOpened()==true)
{

    vid>>camcap;
imshow("Camera_Inp",camcap);
cvtColor(camcap,grayimg,CV_RGB2GRAY);
featureimg.detect(grayimg,keypoints);
drawKeypoints(grayimg,keypoints,surfimg,Scalar(255,255,255),0);
imshow("Surfout",surfimg);
if (waitKey(30)>=0)return -1;


}




return -1;

}
```

Visual Studio gives me the following error:

> Stack around the variable 'keypoints' was corrupted.

The visual Studio debugger gives the error that:

> Stack around the variable 'keypoints' was corrupted

Any help!!